# backbone model save on eve is not working

Tags: python, backbone.js, marionette, eve

I am trying to make a simple DB based backbone/marionette app which is connected to python eve rest api.
After showing a model(title,content) in a form , I edit the content and save it with following:

```
this.model.save({title:t_title,content: t_content},{ headers: {'If-Match' : this.model.get("_etag")}});
```

t_title and t_content are the values/inputs from text fields.

When I hit save button and call above code I get 200 OK for PUT but response returned is following error and no update happens in the DB:

```
{"_status": "ERR", "_issues": {"_updated": "unknown field", "_created": "unknown field", "_id": "unknown field", "_links": "unknown field", "_etag": "unknown field"}}
```

What else do I need to do this update?

Comment: I think you need add to the options (last param of `save`) `patch: true` to send only 2 fields instead of all from your model, as I see your backend model doesn't know about fields like _updated, _created etc.

Comment: I issued an answer :-) based on comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `save()` it sends all model fields, but seems your server side doesn't save all model fields and accept only two fields (`title` and `content`). For this case we may use `patch: true` option it will get an HTTP PATCH request to the server with just the passed-in attributes.

This is fixed code with `patch: true` added in options.

```
this.model.save({title:t_title,content: t_content},{ patch: true, headers: {'If-Match' : this.model.get("_etag")}});
```